# Getting a http_response_code(404) when trying to pass a record id dynamically in phpmyadmin. Am trying to integrate MySQL on-pre with Salesforce

Tags: php, mysql, json, rest, phpmyadmin

I am trying to update one particular record or row corresponding to a id passed dynamically. There is a record belonging to that id. When I give the URL followed with the "?id=3", I am getting a 404 error, saying no such record exists. Would like to know what error I have done. The following is my code.

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/constitute.php';

$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();
$constitute = new Constitute($db);

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$constitute->id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die();
$constitute->name = $data->name;
$constitute->address = $data->address;
$constitute->constitution_type = $data->constitution_type;
$constitute->organisation_id = $data->organisation_id;

if($constitute->update()){
    http_response_code(200);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Constitute was updated."));
}
 else{
    http_response_code(503);
    echo json_encode(array("message" => "Unable to update constitute."));
}
?>
```

The following is the update() method:

```
    function update(){
    $query = "UPDATE
                " . $this->table_name . "
            SET
                name = :name,
                address = :address,
                constitution_type = :constitution_type,
                organisation_id = :organisation_id
            WHERE
                id = ?";
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

    $this->id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->id));
    $this->name=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->name));
    $this->address=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->address));
    $this->constitution_type=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->constitution_type));
    $this->organisation_id=htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($this->organisation_id));

    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $this->id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $this->name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':address', $this->address);
    $stmt->bindParam(':constitution_type', $this->constitution_type);
    $stmt->bindParam(':organisation_id', $this->organisation_id);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also when i try to pass the updated record in postman, I am getting success code. But the record does not get saved. 
Please let me know where I have done mistakes.

Comment: Clearly the problem lies in method readOne() since it is returning a null. Please post the code of that method as well.

Comment: I have added the read_one() method.

Comment: Please show the results of `var_dump($this->id)` and `var_dump($conn->errorInfo())` in `readOne()`.

Comment: I have made some changes to the coding. Now it is getting the record corresponding to the record id and when trying to update the record in postman, i am getting success code 200. But the record is not getting updated in the database. Now I am not sure what mistake that i have done. I am unable to get the update done.